# Default language as "plain text" for minified javascript files, for faster load time

Tags: visual-studio-code

*VScode* loads large (`> 5kb`) minified javascript files **very slow** (at least on my machine) because of what I assume as code highlight and other extensions which apply on `*.js` files.

I am wondering if there is a way to set all `*.min.js` files' default language to `plain text`, or perhaps some smarter way to make minified filed open faster than `~4s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the documentation for [language identifiers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)?

There is a setting (files.associations), which you can use to set associations however you want.

From the docs:

#### Language Identifiers

In Visual Studio Code, each language mode has a unique specific language identifier. That identifier is rarely seen by the user except in the settings, for example, when associating file extensions to a language:

```json
    "files.associations": {
        "*.myphp": "php"
    }
```

Note that casing matters for exact identifier matching `('Markdown' != 'markdown')`

The language identifier becomes essential for VS Code extension developers when adding new language capabilities or when replacing a language support.

Every language defines its id through the languages configuration point in the extension's package.json file:

```json
    "languages": [{
        "id": "java",
        "extensions": [ ".java", ".jav" ],
        "aliases": [ "Java", "java" ]
    }]
```

Language supports are added using the language identifier:

```json
    "grammars": [{
        "language": "groovy",
        "scopeName": "source.groovy",
        "path": "./syntaxes/Groovy.tmLanguage.json"
    }],
    "snippets": [{
        "language": "groovy",
        "path": "./snippets/groovy.json"
    }]
```

```js
languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('php', new PHPCompletionItemProvider(), '.', '$');
```

Comment: Thanks. `files.associations` helped: `"*.min.js": "plaintext"`